# In electron app, when I using worker_thread, an exception occurs after using Command+Q to exit the app

Tags: node.js, electron, worker-thread

My code is very simple:

```
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
let script = `console.log('working...');`;
new Worker(script, { eval: true });
```

I can see `working...` output in the console, but when I exit the program with `command+q`, I see an exception in the console: `my-electron-app/node_modules/_electron@11.3.0@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron exited with signal SIGSEGV`

When I run with `sudo npm start`, I also see a popup about `Electron quit unexpectedly`
[image]

- Electron Version: 11.3.0
- Operating System: macOS 11.2
- Node: 12.18.3
- Chrome: 87.0.4280.141

#### To Reproduce

1. `git clone https://github.com/Vict0r-Chen/electron-worker-threads.git`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start` | `sudo npm start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [information](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27876), using `npm install electron 12.0.0@beta --save-dev` to upgrade electron to `v12.0.0` can solve this problem.

Comment: i'm using 13.0.1 version and facing the same issue while quite or close, and in logs it says electron:build exited with 1 @Victor any idea on it ?